# How to replace the same regexp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been searching but haven't found a solution.

**I have a regexp:**

```
var reg = /^((\d){1,5}(\.|,)(\d{2}))/;
```

**And a string:**

```
var str = '12323.098765421';
```

I'm trying to keep part that match regexp and delete all the rest.

**What I'm doing:**

```
str.replace(/^((\d){1,5}(\.|,)(\d{2}))/, '$1 // can't understand what should I put here to replace first part');
```

Comment: What is the expected output? `12323.09`? See https://regex101.com/r/jF5tV6/1. But why remove? You can use `RegExp#match`: `"12323.098765421".match(/^\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2}/)[0]`.

Comment: didn't get `can't understand what should I put here to replace first part` part.

Comment: @DarthJS: Please clarify and let know if my examples work the way you expect.

Comment: is the goal to round to 2 places?

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew  if you want you can post your answer and I'll vote for it, 'couse you was first

Comment: You forget to use `@` in the comment before the user name, please add it so that the user gets notified. Do you have multiline strings or strings with more than numbers in them?

Comment: Ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine you have a string that starts with a number that conforms to the pattern:

```
1 to 5 digits   +   decimal separator  +  2 digits
```

This pattern may be followed with *any* character, even including a newline. Then, in JS, you can use the following replacement:

```
.replace(/^(\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2})[\s\S]*/, "$1")
```

Where

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `(\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2})` - matches and captures our pattern (with `,` or `.` as decimal separators)
- `[\s\S]*` - matches any 0+ characters, even including a newline.

```js
var re = /^(\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2})[\s\S]*/; 
var str = '12323.098765421';
var result = str.replace(re, "$1");
console.log(result);
```

The `$1` is a backreference to the value captured with Group 1 (formed with the help of a pair of unescaped parentheses).

See more information on [**capturing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Answer (score 1):

The regex will match the required output, since you want to remove the rest then you need to update it like this.

```js
var str = '12323.098765421';

console.log(
  str.replace(/^(\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2})\d+/, '$1')
);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/hG4dS9/1)

---

Or you need to use **[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method to get the matched string

```js
var str = '12323.098765421';

console.log(
  str.match(/^\d{1,5}[.,]\d{2}/)[0]
);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/hG4dS9/2)

Comment: thanks for your reply. maybe I'm doing something wrong but, I'm testing in browser console and the result is something strange:
var x = '12323.09876542';
x.replace(/^(\d){1,5}(\.|,)(\d{2})/, '$1');
result: '3876542'   :(
I'm trying to get '12323.09'

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. match is really what I need

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to round to two places, you can use the following regex:

```
'12323.09876542'.replace(/(\.[0-9][0-9])\d+/, '$1');
```

Or, you can use the `toFixed()` Number function:

```
Number('12323.09876542').toFixed(2)
```